# convert a JPEG to SWF in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, flash, jpeg

Are there any gems / libraries which can be used with Ruby to convert a JPEG into a SWF file with a specific duration?

I need to take a list of JPEGs and convert them into a SWF slideshow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's Ming/Ruby: http://mingruby.rubyforge.org/